# Specify Win32 External Console Window Position

Tags: winapi, console

My console always pops up behind my rendering window (which is large).

I was hoping to be able to make it stay at the bottom of my screen.

Is there a function to set or overwrite the default console window position?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [GetConsoleWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to retrieve the outer window handle.

With this handle just use MoveWindow/SetWindowPos